# Gluon MXNet error when forward with LSTMCell

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, mxnet

Using mxnet 1.1,
When I try to run net(data) on the following network:

```
net = gluon.nn.HybridSequential()
    with net.name_scope():
        net.add(gluon.nn.Embedding(input_dim=MAX_EVENT_INDEX + 1, output_dim=EMBEDDING_VECTOR_LENGTH))
        net.add(gluon.nn.Conv1D(channels=conv1D_filters, kernel_size=conv1D_kernel_size, activation='relu'))
        net.add(gluon.nn.MaxPool1D(pool_size=max_pool_size, strides=2))
        net.add(gluon.rnn.LSTMCell(100))
        net.add(gluon.rnn.DropoutCell(dropout_rate))
        net.add(gluon.rnn.LSTMCell(100))
        net.add(gluon.rnn.DropoutCell(dropout_rate))
        net.add(gluon.rnn.LSTMCell(100))
        net.add(gluon.rnn.DropoutCell(dropout_rate))
        net.add(gluon.nn.Flatten())
        net.add(gluon.nn.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
    net.hybridize()
```

Error: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'states'

Everything works when I use  `gluon.nn.Sequential()` with `net.add(gluon.rnn.LSTM(100, dropout=dropout_rate))`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you look into implementation of [LSTMCell](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/bcf3a8881cb3ff00ee3636599536f203580a79a2/python/mxnet/gluon/rnn/rnn_cell.py#L508) you would notice, that `hybrid_forward` requires explicit `states` argument. LSTM class, using its [base class implementation](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/5474b086757a8df94984fb95622ead0047ac78b4/python/mxnet/gluon/rnn/rnn_layer.py#L177) doesn't require `states` parameter (it can be `None`). So switching from one to another will definitely help you.

`LSTM` class is more than `LSTMCell`. It actually uses `LSTMCell` internally, but it also adds extra functionality on top of it. For example, you can specify `LSTM` to be multilayered or bidirectional, where `LSTMCell` is essentially just a bunch of LSTM-related formulas for calculating gates, c and h.